# Does this sorting algorithm exist? (implemented in Swift)

Tags: swift, algorithm, sorting, int, big-o

This might be a bad question but I am curious.

I was following some data structures and algorithms courses online, and I came across algorithms such as selection sort, insertion sort, bubble sort, merge sort, quick sort, heap sort.. They almost never get close to O(n) when the array is reverse-sorted.

I was wondering one thing: why are we not using space in return of time?

When I organise something I pick up one, and put it where it belongs to. So I thought if we have an array of items, we could just put each value to the index with that value.

Here is my implementation in Swift 4:

```
let simpleArray = [5,8,3,2,1,9,4,7,0]
let maxSpace = 20

func spaceSort(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    guard array.count > 1 else {
        return array
    }
    var realResult = [Int]()
    var result = Array<Int>(repeating: -1, count: maxSpace)

    for i in 0..<array.count{
        if(result[array[i]] != array[i]){
            result[array[i]] = array[i]
        }
    }
    for i in 0..<result.count{
        if(result[i] != -1){
            realResult.append(i)
        }
    }
    return realResult
}

var spaceSorted = [Int]()

var execTime = BenchTimer.measureBlock {
    spaceSorted = spaceSort(array: simpleArray)
}
print("Average execution time for simple array: \(execTime)")
print(spaceSorted)
```

Results I get:

[image]

Does this sorting algorithm exist already?

Is this a bad idea because it only takes unique values and loses the duplicates? Or could there be uses for it?

And why can't I use Int.max for the maxSpace?

Edit: 
I get the error below

> error: Execution was interrupted.

when I use let maxSpace = Int.max

> MyPlayground(6961,0x7000024af000) malloc: Heap corruption detected,
>   free list is damaged at 0x600003b7ebc0
>   *** Incorrect guard value: 0 MyPlayground(6961,0x7000024af000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Thanks for the answers

Comment: you getting any error or something ?

Comment: Its a radix sort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: @Jok3r yes, please see my edit.

Comment: Think about the amount of memory that needs to be allocated for an array of size 2^63. A quick google gives me 74 million terabytes...

Comment: @Sweeper you are right, just thought that what I used wasn't the max index an Array can have but an Int can have.

Comment: what you mean by int.max

Comment: @JoshHomann I checked the Radix sort, it uses digits to sort the items. I put the number with the index = number, so they are not the same algorithms.

Comment: Radix sort is sorting in n time by bucketing so this is a radix sort.

Comment: This is just an extreme version of radix sort: one where your choice of the radix is just as large as the domain of your numbers. So you have a bucket for each individual number. Your numbers are treated as "digits" with a very large base, so that you only have one "digit" for each number. So this is radix sort.

Comment: @trincot bucketing does fit the same idea. Thank you.

Comment: So your question is answered then? I was just responding to your earlier claim about radix sort: *"so they are not the same algorithms"*.

Comment: @trincot yes, it is answered it seems. Although there seems to be many interpretations of Radix Sort then. The idea of bucketing items one by one fits my idea. Could you answer it in an official answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extreme version of radix sort. Quoted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort):

> radix sort is a non-comparative sorting algorithm. It avoids comparison by creating and distributing elements into buckets according to their radix. For elements with more than one significant digit, this bucketing process is repeated for each digit, while preserving the ordering of the prior step, until all digits have been considered. For this reason, radix sort has also been called bucket sort and digital sort.

In this case you choose your radix as `maxSpace`, and so you don't have any "elements with more than one significant digit" (from quote above).

Now, if you would use a Hash Set data structure instead of an array, you would actually not need to really *allocate* the space for the whole range. You would still keep all the loop iterations though (from 0 to `maxSpace`), and it would check whether the hash set contains the value of *i* (the loop variable), and if so, output it.

This can only be an efficient algorithm if `maxSpace` has the same order of magnitude as the number of elements in your input array. Other sorting algorithms can sort with *O(nlogn)* time complexity, so for cases where `maxSpace` is much greater than *nlogn*, the algorithm is not that compelling.